# How to implement conditional CSS?

Tags: html

I have a webpage whose alignment is alright in edit mode, but when my page is in read only, the alignment changes and all textboxes alignment change too. I tried to fix in read only, but then it is not working in editable mode.

Can I fix it by conditional CSS?

Comment: Yous must use less or Sass to do that, or you can use conditonal statement in php

Comment: Without any code, it's hard to help you

Comment: i code my whole page in HTML

Comment: can you gave me one example in php for conditional statement.

Comment: Pure css ,HTML doesnt have this kind of machanic

Comment: You comments of no use for anyone. If you can't provide the information what is request by community members, then you can't expect any help to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

CSS do not have this type of mechanical, if you want to do that, 
your should use

[SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

However Without your code it's hard to give you a concrete example
but you can always do it in PHP or JS

Exemple in PHP

```
<?php
$title = "page4";
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="Dynamic CSS" content="" />
<title>My Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php if(isset($title) && !empty($title)) {  echo '/css/dynamic.css'; }else{ echo '/css/style.css';?>" />
```

This is just an exemple; but again, without your code; 
It's a bit complicated to know your needs

Comment: Thanks i try to fix my issue.

Comment: vote ok if the answer satisfies you, I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the `contenteditable` attribute? If you do, you can use the `[contenteditable]` attribute selector in CSS.

Or you can add different classes to the body element with a small piece of JavaScript and use the class selector in CSS.